# git ignore file header

Tags: git, ignore

In one of my projects all source files have a file header that is being updated by an other program on which I have no influence at all. The files are all checked in into a git repository which I use to track my changes. 
My problem is that when this other program changes the header just slightly I have to look through these changes and check them in, even if they have absolutely nothing to do with the source code.

Is it in git somehow possible to ignore a specific part of every file?

The header always covers the same amount of lines (the first 22 lines) and always looks like this:

```
/**
 * \addtogroup ....
 * \ingroup ...
 * \{
 * 
 * \file        ....
 *
 * \brief       .....
 *
 * \author      $Author: ...... $
 *
 * Revision:    $Revision: .... $
 * Created on:  $Date: ...... $
 *
 * <br>=====================================================<br>
 * <b>Copyright 2012 by ...............</b>
 *
 *  ...........................................................<br>
 *  Restricted rights to use, duplicate or disclose of this code<br>
 *  are granted through contract.
 * <br>=====================================================<br>
 */
```

I did find this "[Keyword-Expansion](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion)" but this seams a bit complicated since I don't want git to update the header (only to ignore it). And also the Ruby script poses a bit of a problem: It is not possible to install ruby on every computer for this.

An other approach would be to remove the header on every 'commit' and add a standard version of that header upon every 'pull' but I don't know how that could be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clean content filter driver you [saw in the Pro Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) is the right solution, and doesn't involve ruby (it involves any scripting language of your choice)

[image]

The goal is, for a certain type of file to:

- detect the header and save a copy (smudge filter)
- compare the header with the saved copy and, if there are any difference, restore that header.

That way, git status wouldn't see the file as modified only because the header has been changed.

Comment: will this show the files as `not changed` in the `git status` output?

Comment: @pqnet yes, that is the goal of those content filter driver depending on their goal: make it seem like the file hasn't change (because the `clean` filter applies first before `git status` compares the index content with the `HEAD`)

Comment: This sounds entreating, but where must the script files be located in order for git to find them?

Comment: @user1498464 anywhere in your `$PATH`, or even versioned in your Git repo.